# Why my keras / tensorflow not using GPUs

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I've looked at some of the other posts about this on stackoverflow, but nothing really seems to help. I have installed only the tensorflow-gpu version and installed keras.

I checked that the gpu is recognized, which it is:

```
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
print('Tensorflow: ', tf.__version__)
```

out

```
[name: "/cpu:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
 incarnation: 17474054933763055451
, name: "/gpu:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 52848230
locality {
  bus_id: 1
}
incarnation: 1990869997540085603
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 
0000:01:00.0"
]
Tensorflow:  1.3.0
```

But when I run the keras model with the tensorflow back-end, it doesn't appear to be any faster than when I run it on my other computer with tensorflow-cpu, without the nvidia. Also looking at the task manager, I'm seeing the spike in CPU usage. I'm new to this and trying to figure it all out, but shouldn't the model/traing be running significantly faster? And should I not be seeing the rise in CPU usage if it's using the GPUs?

If anyone can help, it would greatly be appreciated. I followed all the steps to install tensorflow-gpu, the CUDA, cudnn, etc.

Here's what I have:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 387.92                 Driver Version: 387.92                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. | 


|   0  GeForce GTX 1070   WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   49C    P8     9W /  N/A |   7028MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |


|    0      3740      C   C:\Users\Jason\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe       N/A      |
|    0      3968    C+G   ...dows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe N/A      |
|    0      4392    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe                    N/A      |
|    0      7760    C+G   ...0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WinStore.App.exe N/A      |
|    0      8976    C+G   ...6)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe N/A      |
|    0      9932    C+G   ...rosoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE N/A      |
|    0     12632    C+G   Insufficient Permissions                   N/A      |
|    0     14168    C+G   Insufficient Permissions                   N/A      |
|    0     14548    C+G   ...t_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe N/A      |
|    0     15648    C+G   Insufficient Permissions                   N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and when it's training:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI>nvidia-smi
Fri Oct 13 13:18:23 2017
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 387.92                 Driver Version: 387.92                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |

|   0  GeForce GTX 1070   WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P2    34W /  N/A |   7126MiB /  8192MiB |     15%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |

|    0      3740      C   C:\Users\Jason\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe       N/A      |
|    0      3968    C+G   ...dows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe N/A      |
|    0      4392    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe                    N/A      |
|    0      7760    C+G   ...0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WinStore.App.exe N/A      |
|    0      8976    C+G   ...6)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe N/A      |
|    0      9932    C+G   ...rosoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE N/A      |
|    0     12632    C+G   Insufficient Permissions                   N/A      |
|    0     14168    C+G   Insufficient Permissions                   N/A      |
|    0     14548    C+G   ...t_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe N/A      |
|    0     15648    C+G   Insufficient Permissions                   N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Anaconda Python 3.6; 
Tensorflow-gpu 1.3

1. Download and install Visual Studio 15 (since CUDA 8 not supported by 17,
   need VS 15 instead)
2. CUDA v8.0: set PATH environment variables
3. Updated Nvidia Driver
4. downloaded cudnn-v6.0 for CUDA 8 files instead
   of 5.1. As Tensorflow 1.3 is supporting Cudnn-v6.0: created PATH environment variables for those

UPDATE:

Here's the code I am running. I'm trying to to get the best hyperparameters for epochs and batches. The model is with Keras backend tensorflow.

```
import numpy as np
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import datetime

# Set random seed
np.random.seed(7)

# Create function returning a compiled network
def create_network(optimizer='adam',activation='relu'):

# Start neural network
network = models.Sequential()

# Add fully connected layer with a ReLU activation function
network.add(layers.Dense(units=dim, activation=activation, input_shape=(dim,)))

# Add fully connected layer with a ReLU activation function
network.add(layers.Dense(units=20, activation=activation))

# Add fully connected layer with a sigmoid activation function
network.add(layers.Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))

# Compile neural network
network.compile(loss='mse', # 
                optimizer=optimizer, # Optimizer
                metrics=['mae']) # Accuracy performance metric

# Return compiled network
return network

# Wrap Keras model so it can be used by scikit-learn
neural_network = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_network, verbose=2)


# Create hyperparameter space
epochs = [5, 50, 100, 150]
batches = [1, 5, 10, 100]



# Create hyperparameter options
hyperparameters = dict(epochs=epochs, batch_size=batches)


# Time the process
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

# Create grid search
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=neural_network, param_grid=hyperparameters)

# Fit grid search
grid_result = grid.fit(X, Y)


# View hyperparameters of best neural network
grid_result.best_params_

# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, 
grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))

end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
processing_time = end_time - start_time
print(str(processing_time).split('.')[0])
```

UPDATE 2:
I keep looking for an answer and maybe found something...maybe this is the reason... Can someone verify who knows more than me?

I am using scikit learn to implement the GridSearchCV. And even though I'm using the keras with tensorflow backend, scikit-learn does not utilize GPUs, so could that be the reason? So unless I'm exclusivly using keras, I won't see the GPUs kicking in?

Comment: What is the output of `nvidia-smi` when you are training?

Comment: ok i figured out how to see nvidia-smi (like I said, I'm new). So it shows a difference of 0% to 15% when its training. But it doesn't run significantly faster.

Comment: Have you considered that the model might be just too small to benefit from GPU acceleration?

Comment: Matias, I have not thought about that. I kept the data filtered (into smaller sizes because it just simply couldn't handle all of it..and I also was trying to see if filtering would improve the model). But being new to using TF, just not sure what to expect. But if you're experienced and saying that if the models on the two (CPU vs GPU) are not significantly big to create a huge difference, then that's why I am here asking...

So I'll try expanding it to see a difference. I was just caught off guard seeing the CPU utilization spiking when I'm envisioning the GPU getting the bulk of the work.

Comment: @chitown88 Well we haven't seen your model so what I say is just a hypothesis.

Comment: Could you provide your model definition and training code?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko, I added it in the question above (not sure if you need more info). Also, I saw your in Edinburgh!? I'm there regularly while I've been studying near St. Andrews.